# What's the significance of "-0ubuntu1" at the end of a package version string?

Tags: package-management

Many packages built for Ubuntu seem to have a "-0ubuntu1" suffix (or, more generally, -XubuntuY). For example, the version string for a bleeeding-edge package from the nova project looks like:

```
2011.2~bzr663-0ubuntu1
```

I understand that 2011.2 is a major version, and bzr663 refers to revision 663 in the bzr repository, but what is the meaning associated with 0ubuntu1?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Packages are versioned in a pattern like `<upstream version>-<debian revision>`. In this case, the upstream version is `2011.2~bzr663` & the debian revision is `0ubuntu1`.

Normally in Debian, the revisions are just numbers such, but for Ubuntu, the ubuntu1 following the revision indicates that there are source changes to that Debian revision. 
`0ubuntu1` is a special case, as it's used as a revision that indicates that it's not based on any Debian package of that upstream version (since there wouldn't be a debian revision `0`).

This is common when the Ubuntu package has been upgraded to a new upstream version ahead of Debian.

Comment: Does `-0ubuntu1` always mean there's no Debian-upstream version? I thought that if Debian hadn't altered their upstream source, it would just be `-0` to them.

Comment: Debian revisions generally always start at 1